# How to debug 3delight shader

Tags: shader

I am using 3delight render my scene, I used my shader, but my question is, how do I debug it? I try to use printf ("hello world") in my shader, but I do not see hello world in the output window in maya?

Answer (score 0):

If you render from Maya you can see the output in the Script Editor window. But the Script Editor window is very slow and it's handy to debug shaders in the terminal.

printf is not the only way to debug 3delight shaders. You can output your data to [custom AOVs](https://3delight.atlassian.net/wiki/display/3DFM/AOV+Selector#Custom+Variables). Or you can output your data to the point cloud file using [bake3d](http://www.3delight.com/en/uploads/docs/3delight/3delight_42.html#SEC179) shadeop and then view it with ptcview 3Delight utility. ptcview displays a point cloud file in a window.